# BeautifulSoup4: replace a tag with 2 others

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I want to replace `<h1>title</h1>` with `<b><u>title</u></b>`

I know I can replace `h1` with `b` using `soup.h1.name = "b"`

But is there a way to replace a single tag by several others?

(Special edit for Daniel Roseman: *the tags don't really matter...*)

Comment: Beautiful Soup cannot generate invalid markup, which this is.

Comment: @DanielRoseman could you please explain the meaning of "beverage"? (I'm not native english speaker)

Comment: Do you mean those tags are invalid? (the tags don't really matter in the question)

Answer (score 1):

Use `wrap()`

From the documentation:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup("<p>I wish I was bold.</p>")
soup.p.string.wrap(soup.new_tag("b"))
# <b>I wish I was bold.</b>

soup.p.wrap(soup.new_tag("div"))
# <div><p><b>I wish I was bold.</b></p></div>
```

Comment: it was a bit more complex since I did not want to change all `p` into `b`  but thanks to your help I could figure out the rest of it and write the answer bellow.

Answer (score 1):

thanks to RobertB I could figure out the rest of the answser.

You need:

1. wrap the `h1` with new tags `p`
2. wrap the `h1` with new tags `u`
3. remove the tag `h1` (using `unwrap()` )

```
<!-- language: python -->
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup("<h1>title</h1>", "html.parser")
soup.h1.string.wrap(soup.new_tag("b"))
print(soup) # >>  <h1><b>title</b></h1>

soup.h1.string.wrap(soup.new_tag("u"))
print(soup)  # >> <h1><b><u>title</u></b></h1>

soup.h1.unwrap()
print(soup)   #>> <b><u>title</u></b>
```

Comment: Sorry, stack doesnt recognized it as python code (and not html), if anyone knows how to do...

Comment: @glibdub thanks! How did you do it? (What was wrong in my try?)

Comment: Just use the buttons in the little editor. Don't try to write HTML in a post.

Comment: @RobertB but the code above contains html tags (and it shown properly as python). So what's the trick?

Comment: This system interprets the indented lines as code. Or you can enclose something in single quotes like `this`.